# After upgrading OpenIdDict.AspNetCore to 5 version, validation of token always fails

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, token, openiddict

I have a web application which supports JWT authentication using OpenIdDict.ASPNetCore.
Tokens are generated by other web application using OpenIdDict libraries for a server.

After upgrading OpenIdDict.AspNetCore to 5.0 in the first application, this application tells invalid_token always.

At first I thought that I had to update the OpenIDDict libraries of the second application to 5 version too.
But updating OpenIdDict libraries of the second application doesn't help.

Startup.cs of first application which validates token:

```
 services
 .AddAuthentication("jwt")
 .AddJwtBearer("jwt", options =>
 {
     var cert = new X509Certificate2("publickKey.cer", string.Empty);

     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         ValidIssuer = "<someissuer>",//hidden, I don't want to reveal, sorry
         ValidAudience = "<someaudience>",//hidden, I don't want to reveal, sorry
         IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(cert),
         RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
     };

     options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;                

     options.Backchannel = new HttpClient();

     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
         {
             context.Principal.AddClaim(Claims.Subject, context.Principal.GetClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
             context.Success();
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         }
     };
 });
```

The Startup.cs of the second application which generated tokens:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()

            // Register the OpenIddict core components.
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
                // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                       .UseDbContext<AppDbContext>();

                // Enable Quartz.NET integration.
                options.UseQuartz();
            })

            // Register the OpenIddict server components.
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                // Enable the authorization, logout, token and userinfo endpoints.
                options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/authorize")
                       .SetLogoutEndpointUris("connect/logout")
                       .SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token")
                       .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("connect/userinfo");

                options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
                options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(5));

                // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

                // Note: the sample uses the code and refresh token flows but you can enable
                // the other flows if you need to support implicit, password or client credentials.
                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
                       .AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

                options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

                // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                //options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                  //     .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                //options.AddSigningKey(new X509SecurityKey(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.));

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                options.UseAspNetCore()
                       .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();



                options.SetIssuer(new Uri("someissuer"));//I don't want to reveal, sorry
                var cert = new X509Certificate2("signing-certificate.pfx", string.Empty);
                options.AddSigningKey(new X509SecurityKey(cert));

                var encCert = new X509Certificate2("encryption-certificate.pfx", string.Empty);
                options.AddEncryptionKey(new X509SecurityKey(encCert));

                var dontCheckRedirectUris = new HashSet<string>(new string[]
                {
                    "Baseline",
                    "Review",
                    "Development"
                });

                if (dontCheckRedirectUris.Contains(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")))
                {
                    options.RemoveEventHandler(ValidateClientRedirectUri.Descriptor);
                    options.RemoveEventHandler(ValidateClientPostLogoutRedirectUri.Descriptor);
                    options.RemoveEventHandler(ValidateAuthorizedParty.Descriptor);
                }
            })

            // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
                options.UseLocalServer();

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                options.UseAspNetCore();
                options.Configure(config =>
                {
                    config.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;
                    config.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name;
                });
            });
```